# Laravel: javascript and ajax url is not converted properly

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

When I am trying to initialise javascript and css, I am getting an problem in path. It takes only root URL.

Eg. I have initialize

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script> then
```

it takes

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
```

The file must be

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/myapp/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
```

instead of

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
```

Same problem with the Ajax.

Thanks,
Hasmukh

Comment: Don't take me wrong, but why do you ask if you know the problem. Either create a virtual host which will remove `myapp` from the URL or use `HTML::whatever('myapp/path/to/that/file'); This is not problem, this is your setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is not Laravel but that you're doing your HTML wrong.

If you application doesn't sit on the root of the site, then using root-relative URLs like "/some/url/here" will never work.

Luckily, Laravel can help you out there - you need to use its helpers for including assets:

```
{{ HTML::style('css/site.css') }}
{{ HTML::script('js/site.js') }}
{{ HTML::image('images/logo.png') }}
```

Or if you need to use an asset URL in some other form:

```
<a href="#" data-target="{{{ URL::asset('files/test.pdf') }}}">Download the file</a>
```

You may have to set the URL to your application at the top of `app/config/app.php` though (especially if you need absolute URLs here, for example in HTML emails).